# Error When I deploy Application Page

Tags: sharepoint

I got an error when I demo deploy "Application Page" by Visual Studio 2015 to SharePoint Server 2016 below: Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': The value of the argument '16' is an unsupported enum type. Parameter name: verCompatLevel

Everybody can help me,plz!!!

Comment: Without looking at some of the code, it is impossible to to identify the issue. Please post some of your code if you would like some help..otherwise I am afraid I won't be of much use.

Comment: I'm just create Application Page project and deploy it. I haven't written code yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in SharePoint Preview

In visual studio I changed the SharePoint Product Version of the package to 15 instead of 16 and my solution deployed successfully.

I guess it will fixed in the RTM